# How to load node custom fields metadata?

Tags: 7, entities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why node custom fields weren’t saved when adding node programmatically?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53265/why-node-custom-fields-werent-saved-when-adding-node-programmatically)

This question is related to [Why node custom fields weren't saved when adding node programmatically?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53265/why-node-custom-fields-werent-saved-when-adding-node-programmatically).

I think that I found why I can't store value in custom fields.

Two Drupal sites A, B. Same server. From site A I want to create node on site B using database access only.

But when I try to get target node type in client sites (A):

```
db_set_active('gallery');
field_info_instances("node","image") 
db_set_active();
```

I am getting empty array. Inside target site B function returns correct fields definition.

I am looking for function to load node custom fields metadata? I don't want to bootstrap site B from site A.

Comment: I may be dense here, but how is this different than the original question?

Comment: I get you are saying that what suggested in the accepted answer for the other question is not working for you. If that is the case, then you should not accept that answer in the other question, comment about the suggested solution not working, and waiting for another solution. Creating another question to say the proposed solution doesn't work is not the way to go. I am sorry if I sound dense.

Comment: You are right, I'll delete question